# Fastest way to exclude characters in a query

Tags: mysql, performance

I want to union two tables, but want to exclude any names that start with '?'. (In fact any that contain '?', but all the offendors start with '?'.)

```
SELECT NAME, AGE, LOCATION 
FROM TABLEONE
WHERE NAME NOT LIKE CONCAT('?%')
UNION ALL
SELECT NAME, AGE, LOCATION 
FROM TABLETWO
WHERE NAME NOT LIKE CONCAT('?%')
LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

This is really slow.  Can I speed it up with a better query, or with indexing?

It is using a concat, as this is code that I have inherited.  I expect concat is not the best choice, but I thought I'd show the code as I've received it.

My understanding is indexes do not help in wildcard searches.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you calling `CONCAT` with only one argument?

Comment: why concat('?%') and not just LIKE '?%' ?

Comment: Inherited code - original query edited for clarity.

Comment: If `NAME` is indexed I'd expect the `NAME NOT LIKE '?%'` to be pretty quick unless you have a ton of results. That's just a guess, but I'm almost positive that using the `CONCAT` will kill any chance of optimization.

Comment: `LIKE` should be able to use indexes if `if the argument to LIKE is a constant string that does not start with a wildcard character`.  So lose the `CONCAT`, add an index to `NAME` and see if that helps. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html

Comment: I did a few tests and it seems that `LIKE` can use indexes (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07f3d/7), but `NOT LIKE` doesn't (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07f3d/3).

Comment: Unless most of the names start with '?', the index discussion is quite moot. If you're returning, say, 90% of the rows, a full table scan will be the fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

Use REGEXP for the same:

```
SELECT NAME, AGE, LOCATION FROM TABLEONE WHERE NAME REGEXP '^([^?])'
UNION ALL
SELECT NAME, AGE, LOCATION FROM TABLETWO WHERE NAME REGEXP '^([^?])'
```

Comment: This works, but I don't think it'll use indexes or be any faster.

Answer (score 0):

If there's something special about all the entries whose name begins with a ?, you probably want to have another field in the database to flag them. It's not as good just using the name - you run into problems like this, with it being slow.

Comment: Unfortunately it's users (the public) entering in 'tests' to the field. It occurs about 0.1% of the time. But then I have 300 million records, so it's still a few!